# Max no of buttons on a single page

Tags: xamarin.forms

How many buttons one can have on a single page in xamarin.forms?
I am using a grid and in each grid another grid with scrolled stack layouts here in these stack layouts im adding buttons dynamically. This results in more than a 100 buttons will it overload the interrupts

Comment: Could you share the code you used to add buttons which overload interrupts?

Comment: There is no way to accurately answer this question.  100 buttons on a single page may be possible technically, but it would be a horrible UX.